# How to create a search tool that displays files in a folder as downloadable links by entering PARTIAL file names in php/html?

Tags: php, html, search, frontend

I'm currently learning PHP, HTML, MySQL (as a hobby) and recently I got stuck trying to create a search tool in a web page where you can enter PART of the file name and it will display matching results as downloadable links

Since I've only learned/learning HTML and PHP to create web pages, I tried some things I know but none of them worked the way I wanted it to. Then I started googling and found some code.

here's one I've tried :

```
<?php
$dir = "uploads/../";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file == $_POST['file_name']){
                echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

it works BUT you have to enter the EXACT file name (extension and all) to get any results. This is impractical for what I want because I only remember parts of the file name

Answer (score 0):

If you were to combine `glob` for finding files in a directory and `preg_grep` to match items in an array using a regex expression like this

```
    if( isset( $_POST['file_name'] ) ){

        $dir='uploads/../';
        $pttn=sprintf( '@(%s)@', preg_quote( $_POST['file_name'] ) );
        $files=preg_grep( $pttn ,glob( $dir . '*.*' ) );


        if( count( $files ) > 0 ){
            foreach( $files as $file ){
                printf('<a href="%2$s%1$s">%1$s</a>', $file, $dir );
            }
        }
    }
```

To avoid the full path in the url try along these lines perhaps. You take the file + extension using `pathinfo` and combine this with the `$dir` variable

```
$basename=pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
printf('<a href="%2$s%1$s">%2$s%1$s</a>', $basename, $dir );
```

You should find ( not tested ) that you can supply a partial name and it will match all files that match the regex

Comment: hey thanks :D it works. The only issue is the downloadable link displays the entire path instead of just the file name. currently trying to tweak the code so it just shows the file name. Is there a way to get around this?